# Recommended mutli-tab terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator

I'm using Ubuntu 18 default setup with GNOME Terminal. I can do New Tab, but I'm not finding a way to name/title an *existing* tab: there is no `Set Title` option in the Terminal menu, and I can't find a way to get `gnome-terminal --tab --title SOMETHING` to operate on existing tab. Currently I have defined these in my .bashrc:

```
tt() { [[ -n $1 ]] && echo -ne "\e]0;$1\a" || echo Need tab title; } 
ntt() { [[ -n $1 ]] && gnome-terminal --tab --title $1 || echo Need tab title; }
```

I have tried guake and termit and tilix are the only ones out of a dozen that seem to support renaming tab from GUI (several that I tried were unstable or output a bunch of stuff to stderr, would rather not use -- like terminology and terminator).

The custom commands work, but

1. is there a way to set GNOME Terminal tab title of existing tab from command line without such arcane sequence of escape characters (as seen https://askubuntu.com/a/22417/738406)
2. is there a better terminal emulator, ie one that is at least as good as GNOME Terminal but also supports doing #1 and additionally set tab title from GUI?

Comment: @Fox yes I know I have done that in the meantime but would rather find out if there is a builtin solution rather than re-invent the wheel, seems like such a basic need

Comment: To whoever downvoted, I have added more info about what I tried.

Comment: `xfce4-terminal` provides an option to rename a tab by right-clicking on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I was very frustrated when gnome-terminal stopped allowing tab naming.  My solution was to create a function that is stored in my .bash_functions file that is sourced by my .bash_profile.  This is that function:

function tabname() {
    newName="$1"
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$newName\007"'
}

You use it by switching to the tab you want to rename, such as "myTab":

tabname "myTab"

Comment: Thanks but this is too similar to what I already describe in my question (see tt and NTT functions). This approach works, but also means everyone is reinventing the wheel, I was hoping I had missed something obvious that would not require this approach.